# DataTables - a version of drawCallback event that gives access to newly loaded AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When my DataTable is initialized with the first AJAX call to the server, I can access all the data returned by the server in the "initComplete" callback. But I need to execute a custom piece of code after the AJAX call returns and after the table redraws itself using the new data. Is it possible to access all the data in the "drawCallback" callback or is there a better place somewhere to put my code?

Comment: Have you tried the second example in [the drawCallback docs examples](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback#Examples)?

Comment: I need a bit more than the data inside the table. My server returns something like `new { Data = new[] { ... }, AdditionalData = "Alert to show" }`. I need that AdditionalData.

Comment: then you could simply save the Ajax result in a higher scope variable that the drawCallback's callback can see..